# Vbulletin post template - ad_thread_first_post_content

Tags: vbulletin

I am trying to include the ad_thread_first_post_content template in postbit and postbit legancy template, using this code

```
   <vb:if condition="$post['isfirstshown']">

                                  {vb:raw ad_location.thread_first_post_content}
                                {vb:raw ad_location.ad_thread_first_post_content}

</vb:if>
```

If i add some test content above this conditional, that content appears on post page but the content of the template named ad_thread_first_post_content, do not appear in post page.
I have added the above content after

```
   <div class="postbody">
<div class="postrow">
    <vb:if condition="$post['title'] OR $show['messageicon']">
    <h2 class="posttitle icon">
        <vb:if condition="$show['messageicon']"><img src="{vb:raw post.iconpath}" alt="{vb:raw post.icontitle}" /> </vb:if>{vb:raw post.title}
    </h2>
    </vb:if>
```